# My .append using a var value doesn't append anything! (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, append, var

I am having a problem with this bit of jQuery.

```
var item = $("#iteminput").val();   

$("#add").on("click", function(){
    $("ul").append("<li>" + (item) + "</li>")
});
```

When I type something in the input, then click the add button, it seems to think the var is blank.

Any ideas? Sorry for asking such a newbie question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the value you typed at the time of the click like this:

```
$("#add").on("click", function(){
    var item = $("#iteminput").val();
    $("ul").append("<li>" + item + "</li>")
});
```

You were fetching the value at the time of the page load before any typing has happened.

Comment: That seems so simple now that you point it out. Sorry for the bother, and thanks for your help!

Comment: Just wanted to point out, you can keep it outside the function if you like being able to access it by the rest of the code... You can declare it outside, but set it inside.

Comment: @mark.hch - why would you want to create a global variable (which are generally undesirable anyway) and store a potentially out-of-date value of the field vs. just getting the value directly from the field whenever you need it?

Comment: @user3858292 - since you're new here, do you know that when someone answers your question, you can indicate the best answer to the community here by checking the green checkmark to the left of that answer.  This rewards the answerer and earns you some reputation points for following the right procedure here.